# Add wiringPi lib to cmake on RaspberryPi

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi

for my project in c++ I wanted to create a cmake file to compile and link everything together.
This is my dir structure so far:

```
"quadro/minimu9-ahrs" alias home
|-build
|-include
|-src
```

in my home dir I have this 'CMakeLists.txt' file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project(minimu)

set(HEADER_FILES $("include/*.h")
include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(minimu ${SOURCES})
add_definitions(-std=c++0x -lwiringPi -lpthread)

#install(TARGETS minimu DESTINATION /usr/lib)
```

in my 'src' dir I got all the .cpp files, and in 'include' all my headers. When I'm comiling, I go into my build dir, delete everything existing in there (from previous builds) and type

```
cmake ..
make
```

my problem in now, that my main.cpp in src uses '#include wiringPi.h', but when I make the project it gives me the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/quadro/minimu9-ahrs/build $ make
Scanning dependencies of target minimu
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/src/L3G.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/src/LSM303.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/src/I2CBus.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/src/MinIMU9.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable minimu
CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `frequency_thread(void*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `digitalWrite'
main.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `digitalWrite'
CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `signalHandler(int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `digitalWrite'
main.cpp:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `digitalWrite'
CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `wiringPiSetup'
main.cpp:(.text+0x184): undefined reference to `pinMode'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/build.make:185: recipe for target 'minimu' failed
make[2]: *** [minimu] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/minimu.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

so how do I tell the compiler in cmake where to find and how to use the wiringPi lib? And is there an easier way, instead of deleting everything in my build folder before cmaking? Like it compiles all the 'static' files one time, and only adds the changing file (=main.cpp) everytime again.

Further I want to execute my program everywhere like

```
sudo minimu
```

instead of going into the 'build' dir and type

```
sudo ./minimu
```

Thanks if you can help me guys!
And sorry if my english isn't that good :)
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a flag `-L <path>` to compiler flags.

```
add_definitions(-std=c++0x -L/path/to/libwringPi.???.(so|a) -lwiringPi -lpthread)
```

I do not understand, why you clear the build dir before running cmake (this is not critique. I really do not understand, There might be a reason I dont know) . make checks if the sources are newer than the last compile output and compiles only the files, that are affected. But this works only, if do not delete the build targets.

To install the resulting program uncomment the install directive in you cmake and setup a target dir that's in you PATH. You can also create a dir /home//bin or so. Prepend it to the PATH environment variable and configure the target of you install directive with the new path. Then, in addition to `cmake` and `make` you have to perform a `make install`.

Comment: how should the path look like? as absolute path, or like when I put the wiringPi folder inside my include: "-L/include/wiringPi/" ?

Comment: The path should be the absolute path to the directory where the libWiring.so is located. Perhaps -L/lib/libWiring/ or so.

Comment: Now I have access to a raspberry and was not able to resist building wiring pi. I built it with the build script. It produced a correct installation of the dynamic libraries so  -lwiringPi like you used it before should be sufficient to reference the library from the compiler. Where did you fetched the library from? Hier is a link to how to install the library. .http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/

Comment: Ah I forgot: The path to the dynamic lib is /usr/lib/libwiringPi.so after such a build.

Comment: yep, I installed it that way, and I also get this line in /usr/lib/:
#lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      34 Mai 24 21:09 libwiringPi.so -> /usr/local/lib/libwiringPi.so.2.25  so I tried it with "-L/usr/lib/libwiringPi.so" and also with "-L/usr/local/lib/libwiringPi.so.2.25" and neither way worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, and I already used "g++ main.cpp -lwiringPi" for compiling a simple file, and it worked.

Comment: You mean compiling and linking. You produced an a.out? Then you can start it and find out if the dynamic linking works.

Answer (score 9):

I just figured this out today thanks to Sebastian over at github.

Assuming that you have wiringPi installed, the easiest thing to do is to make a FindWiringPi.cmake with the following:

```
find_library(WIRINGPI_LIBRARIES NAMES wiringPi)
find_path(WIRINGPI_INCLUDE_DIRS NAMES wiringPi.h)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(wiringPi DEFAULT_MSG WIRINGPI_LIBRARIES WIRINGPI_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

And then put this in the folder where cmake looks for it's modules. For Ubuntu it's /usr/share/cmake-2.x/Modules. It's basically the same path for pi too.

Then in your CMakeLists.txt file use:

```
# Locate libraries and headers
find_package(WiringPi REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED) 

# Include headers
include_directories(${WIRINGPI_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 

# Link against libraries
target_link_libraries(<yourProjectName> ${WIRINGPI_LIBRARIES}) 
target_link_libraries(<yourProjectName> ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

The pthread module is a stock package and should be on your system already. So then navigate to your folder and do a `cmake ./` and then `make`. If this doesn't work the first time, then remove your CMakeCache.txt with `rm CMakeCache.txt` and try again. MAKE SURE THAT YOU REMOVE THE CACHE AND NOT THE LIST!!

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the QA, I figured out this can be done in a simpler manner (Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+) without altering anything in `/usr/share/cmake-x.y/Modules`. After your `add_executable` line, add the following

```
find_library(WIRINGPI_LIBRARIES NAMES wiringPi)
target_link_libraries(<executable_name> ${WIRINGPI_LIBRARIES})
```

For example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(OpenInsulin)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# Include headers
include_directories(.)

add_executable(OpenInsulin
        main.cpp
        MCP9600.cpp
        MCP9600.h)

# Link against wiringPi
find_library(WIRINGPI_LIBRARIES NAMES wiringPi)
target_link_libraries(OpenInsulin ${WIRINGPI_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I keep getting CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
WIRINGPI_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "blink" in directory /home/thomas/CLionProjects/blink